# Warning: Error in if: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed RStudio(shiny)

Tags: python, r, shiny, tensorflow

This code always gives me the error:

> Warning: running command 'C:/Users/Madhurima/Anaconda3/python
>   C:/Users/Madhurima/Anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/models/tutorials/image/imagenet/classify_image.py/classify_image.py
>   --image_file /tmp/imagenet/cropped_panda.jpg' had status 2 Warning in renderPlot(...) : NAs introduced by coercion Warning: Error in if:
>   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

```
    #
    # This is the server logic of a Shiny web application. You can run the 
    # application by clicking 'Run App' above.
    #
    # Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
    # 
    #    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
    #

    library(shiny)
    library(wordcloud)

    # Define server logic required to draw a histogram
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {
      PYTHONPATH <- "C:/Users/Madhurima/Anaconda3"  #should look like /Users/yourname/anaconda/bin if you use anaconda python distribution in OS X
      CLASSIFYIMAGEPATH <- "C:/Users/Madhurima/Anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/models/tutorials/image/imagenet/classify_image.py" #should look like ~/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models/image/imagenet

      outputtext <- reactive({
        ###This is to compose image recognition template###
        inFile <- input$file1 #This creates input button that enables image upload
        template <- paste0(PYTHONPATH,"/python ",CLASSIFYIMAGEPATH,"/classify_image.py") #Template to run image recognition using Python
        if (is.null(inFile))
        {
          res <- system(paste0(template," --image_file /tmp/imagenet/cropped_panda.jpg"),intern=T)
     } 
        else { #Initially the app classifies cropped_panda.jpg, if you download the model data to a different directory, you should change /tmp/imagenet to the location you use. 
          res <- system(paste0(template," --image_file ",inFile$datapath),intern=T) #Uploaded image will be used for classification
           }
      })

      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        ###This is to create wordcloud based on image recognition results###
        df <- data.frame(gsub(" *\\(.*?\\) *", "", outputtext()),gsub("[^0-9.]", "", outputtext())) #Make a dataframe using detected objects and scores
        names(df) <- c("Object","Score") #Set column names
        df$Object <- as.character(df$Object) #Convert df$Object to character
        df$Score <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Score)) #Convert df$Score to numeric
        s <- strsplit(as.character(df$Object), ',') #Split rows by comma to separate rows
        df <- data.frame(Object=unlist(s), Score=rep(df$Score, sapply(s, FUN=length))) #Allocate scores to split words
        # By separating long categories into shorter terms, we can avoid "could not be fit on page. It will not be plotted" warning as much as possible
        wordcloud(df$Object, df$Score, scale=c(4,2),
                  colors=brewer.pal(6, "RdBu"),random.order=F) #Make wordcloud
      })

      output$outputImage <- renderImage({
        ###This is to plot uploaded image###
        if (is.null(input$file1)){
          outfile <- "/tmp/imagenet/cropped_panda.jpg"
          contentType <- "image/jpg"

          #Panda image is the default
        }else{
          outfile <- input$file1$datapath
          contentType <- input$file1$type
          #Uploaded file otherwise
        }

        list(src = outfile,
             contentType=contentType,
             width=350)
      }, deleteFile = FALSE)
    })**strong text****strong text**
```

Comment: Does running the command: `C:/Users/Madhurima/Anaconda3/python C:/Users/Madhurima/Anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/models/tutorials/image/imagenet/classify_image.py/classify_image.py --image_file /tmp/imagenet/cropped_panda.jpg` from your command line work? Probably not, since it is returning  status 2, and status 0 means sucessful.

Comment: i tried this and its actually working for me Mike